# Software installation script says "loopback not defined in ifconfig"

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I'm trying to install a software by IBM in CentOS 7 and the installation script does a few environment checkings to make sure everything is working. The script is saying that "loopback not defined in ifconfig".

The problem is coming from here:

```
(sshexec) Executing 'sudo /sbin/ifconfig lo | grep "inet addr:127.0.0.1" | wc -l' on      localhost.localdomain.com as biadmin
(sshexec) Result: 0
```

It seems that the script is expecting this line "inet addr:127.0.0.1" in **ifconfig lo**, but  my **ifconfig lo** says "inet 127.0.0.1"

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    loop  txqueuelen 0  (Loopback Local)
    RX packets 13196  bytes 2606382 (2.4 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 13196  bytes 2606382 (2.4 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I don't know much about networks but my loopback seems to be configured just fine. Any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little hacky, but you could temporarily install a shell script "wrapper" program that massages `ifconfig` output into the form expected by the install script.

Start by renaming `/sbin/ifconfig` to `/sbin/ifconfig.real`. Then create a new file named `/sbin/ifconfig`, containing this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /sbin/ifconfig.real "$@" | sed 's/ inet / inet addr:/'
```

This will run the original `ifconfig` program, which you've renamed, and add "addr:" to the right place in each line of output. Make your new script executable and test it to make sure it produces the right output:

```
$ chmod a+x /sbin/ifconfig
$ /sbin/ifconfig lo
```

Run the installer. Once you're done, remove the wrapper script and rename `/sbin/ifconfig.real` back to `/sbin/ifconfig`.

Comment: Thank you, I think that's exactly what I need. I'll try it out.